# Check if string contains one of the listed format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a search procedure that checks whether the content contains any of the listed file formats. Here's what I've come up with so far, but it's not working for some reason.

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = 'somefile.png';

IF @str LIKE '%(png|jpg|svg|gif)%'
SELECT 'true'
ELSE
SELECT 'false';
```

I need to pass the desired formats into a string variable so I can't use the "OR" operator.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any concept of regex. You can try `LIKE` with wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

To start you with the solution check below code.

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = 'somefile.png';
DECLARE @var nvarchar(max) = 'png|jpg|svg|gif';

IF RIGHT(@str,3) IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@var, '|') )
  SELECT 'true'
ELSE
  SELECT 'false';
```

You can make it more generic by changing it to accept more then 3 characters in the file extension.